# How can I mux/demux RTP media from one stream?

Tags: voip, rtp

Currently, I'm finding a lib able to stream video from multiple sources through one RTP Stream (one connection). Anbody have sugesstion on it?

Actually, I figured out that Opal 3.8 is VoIP lib, supported RTP/H264. But I don't know whether it can support mux/demux rtp media from one stream? If no, can you give me some suggesstion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few RTP stacks around and which one you use depends on which language you are going to be developing in, [pjmedia](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/index.htm) is a good cross-platform one.

RTP streams can only carry media from a single source so you won't be able to multiplex multiple video streams into a single RTP stream, see Synchronization source (SSRC) on page 9 of the [RTP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt). What you could do is have two separate RTP streams (different SSRC's) being sent from the same socket which would mean you're mutliplexing them as far as the network is concerned. If you actually want to combine multiple video streams into a single RTP stream then you need to mix them which is a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: Thank for your information. May be we should advertise a new SDP Media stream then streaming through the new one.

Comment: You would be much better off using a separate RTP stream for each media stream. If you are using SIP signalling you can specify mutliple streams in a single SDP payload.

Comment: What about rtpmp2tpay / rtpmp2tdepay? I think they are made for exactly this use case?